# Parametrisation of a differential equation by arc length

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

Suppose I have the following PDE:

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[(1-y)^3y^3\left(\sin \theta + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\cos \theta\right) \right]$

I notice that I can simplify the expression $\sin \theta + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\cos \theta$ with $R \sin (\theta + \alpha)$, such that it reduces my PDE to:

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[(1-y)^3y^3\sqrt{1+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}^2}\sin \left(\theta +\arctan\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)\right) \right]$

I then notice that $\sqrt{1+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}^2}$ can be reduced to $\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}$, where $s$ is the arclength, and that $ \arctan\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right) = \theta$, such that my equation can be written:

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[(1-y)^3y^3\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}\sin2\theta\right]$

My question is this. I wish to now reduce the equation so that it is a function of $s$ and not $y$ entirely, but I am not sure with how to deal with the $y$ and $y_t$ terms. Can anyone give me any pointers?